# Laravel 5 eloquent relationship between 4 tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have four tables, i used Laravel 5.2 eloquent method

```
Municipalities
id
name
---------------
Barangays
id
name
municipality_id
----------------
Puroks
id
name
barangay_id
----------------
Households
id
name
purok_id
```

I have attached also hasMany(), belongsTo() relationship respectively in each model.

So that:

```
Municipalities hasMany() Barangays hasMany() Puroks hasMany() Households
```

and

```
Households belongsTo() Puroks belongsTo() Barangays belongsTo() Municipalities
```

> I want to know is there a way to get the name of the municipality
>   through Household query?

like

```
  query = Household->purok->barangay->municipality->name
```

And I will have little query to get the name of household, purok, barangay and municipality in one query.

I usually do it with manually leftjoin these tables.

Comment: try eager loading i.e Household::with('purok')->with('barangays')->with('Municipalities')->find(1);

Comment: or the nested version Household::with('purok.barangays.municipalities')->find(1)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you can get it by including joins in your query like:

```
// $data will have all the columns of Households joined with Municipalities..
    $data = \DB::table('Households')
                    ->select('Households.*', 'Municipalities.*')
                    ->join('Puroks', 'Households.purok_id', '=', 'Puroks.id')
                    ->join('Barangays', 'Puroks.barangay_id', '=', 'Barangays.id')
                    ->join('Municipalities', 'Barangays.municipality_id', '=', 'Municipalities.id')
                    ->get();
```

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: @never You can even select the other tables in this query by adding those tables inside select().

Comment: Yeah I do this, I usually do leftjoin(). I want to know if there are shortcuts in doing this using Laravel eloquent relationships.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you can get it by

```
Households::with(['Puroks', 'Puroks.Barangays', 'Puroks.Barangays.Municipalities'])->get()->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a hasManyThrough relationship on Municipalities to Puroks as:

```
Municipalities hasManyThrough() Puroks // public function puroks()
Puroks belongsTo() Municipalities // public function municipalities()
```

and then using it with `hasMany()` from Puroks to Households you can get the results.

```
$result = Household::whereHas('puroks', function($query) {
        $query->whereHas('municipalities', function($qry) {
            $qry->whereNotNull('name');
        });
    });
```

Try this, I am not sure that it will surely work, but it may help you.